# How do I set up routes with express and react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I have problem with routes, namely I have this error.
POST http://localhost:4000/routes/api/user/register 404 (Not Found)

This is my server.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const config = require("./../server/config");
const cors = require("cors");
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const registerRouter = require("./routes/api/user");
app.use("/user", registerRouter);
app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
);
module.exports = app;
```

And this is my route:

```
const router = require("express").Router();

router.route("/register").post((req, res, next) => {
  const { body } = req;
  const { password, name } = body;
  let { email } = body;
  return res.send({
    success: true,
    message: "Signed up",
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Lastly this is how I handle post request

```
  const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/routes/api/user/register", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.success) {
          console.log(res.message);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

This is structure of my project

server/routes/api/user

src/

Where is the problem ?

Comment: from your code it should just be `http://localhost:4000/user/register`

Comment: when I do http://localhost:4000/user/register there is no reactions nor any error

Comment: I think I've messed here 
const registerRouter = require("./routes/api/user");
app.use("/user", registerRouter);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
app.use(registerRouter);//first change here
```

then in router use this

```
 const express = require("express");
 const router = new express.Router();
 router.post("/register", (req, res, next) => {
  const { password, name, email } = req.body;
console.log('your message!!!')
  res.send({
    success: true,
    message: "Signed up",
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

use this url in fetch `http://localhost:4000/register`

Comment: @Pawel try this one now

Comment: after your changes there is no error or any message in the console, but when I check "Network"  I see this request with status 200 and I see respond {message: "Signed up"
success: true} Why I cant see this on console neither in terminal ?

Comment: Because its  HTTP request and you aren't logging anything in console. If you want to see in console write console.log('message') in post callback.

Comment: also you probably want `res.json` not `res.send`